# Replacing all data in a pyqt table model

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm working on a game that involves moving 'gems' between a storage bank and a player. I'm using a QTableView to display the current gems of the player with a QAbstractTableModel as the model. When the app is initialized I set up the model like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_Widget.__init__(self)
    
    self.setupUi(self)
    self._headers = [Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLACK]
    self.playerGemsTable = GemTableView(self.layoutWidget)
    self.gameActions = GameActions(["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"])
    #populate the player gems table
    data:list = [ ["Currently held", self.gameActions.currentPlayer.gems]]       
    self._playerGemModel = TokenStoreModel(data, self._headers, [0])
    self.playerGemsTable.setModel(self._playerGemModel)
```

So far, so good. When I run my app it displays a table with the correct data. The problem now is figuring out how to update the model. I'm not changing individual items. I'm calling a method of the GameActions class that handles all the calculations and updates all the gem quantities. My initial thought was to set up a signal to respond to a successful 'save' and then set _playerGemModel.data with the new value of self.gameActions.currentPlayer.gems . Looking at the available methods for QAbstractTableModel however, there doesn't appear to be any way to do a mass update. All the methods seem to be designed to update a single value at a specific row and column.

Am I missing something? Is looping through the data and updating items one by one really the only option?

Comment: The model emits `dataChanged` when the data (*not* the size or layout) changes, so it's completely up to you if emit it for individual indexes, ranges or the complete model. It's unclear, though, if that's your case or not, as your description of the update is a bit vague, and you didn't provide a [mre] of the model or your attempt of that implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The available method in the tablemodel for updating the data, `setData()`, is meant to be used by the view, from where you can only edit one datum at the time. But you're not limited to that. You can write any method you like to mass update the data. Just make sure it emits an appropriate `dataChanged` signal so the view knows which data have changed.

Comment: That's what I want to do but I keep going in circles. Emitting the dataChanged event requires an index but I can't get the index without specifying row and column.

Comment: And why can't you specify a row and column?

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize that you could provide a range rather than having to loop through all the items.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found what I was looking for here: [PyQt5 Question about refreshing view/mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/dw86kp/pyqt5_question_about_refreshing_viewmodel/)

Once I figured out that you could supply the dataChanged signal with a range, it made things much easier. I simply added a method to my model class that takes the updated data and emits a dataChanged event with a range from the top-left cell to the bottom-right. The final result ended up looking like this:

```
class TokenStoreModel( QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, gems: list[ str, TokenStore], headers):
        super(TokenStoreModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = gems
        self._headers = headers

    def refreshData(self, gems):
        self._data = gems
        topLeft = self.createIndex(0,0)
        bottomRight = self.createIndex(len(gems), len(self._headers))
        self.dataChanged.emit(topLeft, bottomRight)
```

So now in my controller I can simply have a method like:

```
def refreshPlayerGems(self):
    data:list = [ ["Currently held", self.gameActions.currentPlayer.gems]]
    self._playerGemModel.refreshData( data)
```

that gets called after a successful save.

Comment: You could have found that much easier by looking at the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged

Comment: Also: 1. use `index()`, not `createIndex()`, which has a different purpose; 2. the `bottomRight` index is wrong, because it goes beyond the range: it should be the index of the last row and last column, but right now you're using `len()`, which results in the "next" row and column, so you should change it to `self.index(len(gems) - 1, len(self._headers) - 1)`; note that right now it "works" just because by default QAbstractItemView automatically updates the whole view whenever the two indexes are not identical, but both arguments *must* be valid indexes anyway (and belong to the same parent).

Comment: @musicamente "_by default QAbstractItemView automatically updates the whole view whenever the two indexes are not identical_" That doesn't seem to be the case. Did you mean "when at least one index is out of range". When I hack some of my code to emit the wrong range (but within the existing confines) the view doesn't update everything.